# How to use crc32 from zlib in swift (Xcode 9)

Tags: swift, zlib, xcode9, crc32

I'm new to swift/xcode and am trying to use the crc32 function that, as mentioned [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/CRC-32#Swift), is provided in zlib from libz.dylib .

I've modified the code so that I am now trying:

`let message1 = "some message".first?.value!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
let crc = crc32(CLong(0), UnsafePointer<Bytef>(strcat!.bytes), UInt(message1!.length))`

however I am encountering the error: `use of unresolved identifier 'crc32'`.

Could anyone help me to figure out what step I might be missing in trying to use the crc32 function?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do the import?

Comment: Hey @MarkAdler ! Yes, here's what I did to import libz.dylib : Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries > + > Add other
While in the file selection window press: "CMD"+Shift+G (i.e. Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
From /user/lib find and add : libz.dylib

Comment: I meant, did you have "import zlib" in your code?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5:

```
import zlib

let data = Data(base64Encoded: "SGF2ZSBhIG5pY2UgZGF5ISA6KQ==")!
let checksum = data.withUnsafeBytes { crc32(0, $0.bindMemory(to: Bytef.self).baseAddress, uInt(data.count)) }
print("crc32: 0x\(String(format:"%08X", checksum))")
```